# Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 doesn't work "Open for Editing in Android Studio" in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

The first execution at project creation is ok.
After adding Firebase it doesn't work "Open for Editing in Android Studio"
The error showing below....

[image]

Comment: What happens when you use Android Studio Giraffe?

Comment: I got ok with Android Studio Giraffe...

Comment: Then, I would stick with that. Might be an issue with Hedgehog.